# int to System.Windows.GridLength - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, gridlength

How can I convert int to System.Windows.GridLength in VB, NET so that I can set the height of a grid row in Silverlight (xaml).

**In xaml file:**

```
<RowDefinition Height="0" x:Name="rowerror"  />
```

**In VB.NET:**

```
rowerror.Height = CType(30, System.Windows.GridLength)
```

This as I wrote in VB.NET. I know I'm wrong, but how do you do if the int to System.Windows.GridLength so that the height of the "rowerror" whether that be 30?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
rowerror.Height = new GridLength(30)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx) provides an example of this using a [GridLengthConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlengthconverter.aspx)..

```
Dim myGridLengthConverter As System.Windows.GridLengthConverter = New System.Windows.GridLengthConverter()

...

rowerror.Height = CType(myGridLengthConverter.ConvertFromString("30"), GridLength)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!